# Taking screenshots of widgets on a separate thread QT C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to periodically take screenshots of a list of widgets. I've connected a slot to a timer and once the timer ends the slot below is executed.

```
void SlotUpdateScreenshots()
{
    QtConcurrent::run([=]() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);

    QList<Workspace*> workspaces = GetAllWorkspaces();

        for (int i = 0; i < workspaces.size(); i++) {
            m_WorkspaceScreenshots[workspaces.at(i)].clear();

            std::map<WorkspacePoint, Layout*>layoutMap = workspaces.at(i)->GetlayoutMap();

            //Declare a list out layouts
            QList<Layout*> LayoutList;

            for (auto layout : layoutMap)
            {
                LayoutList.append(layout.second);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < LayoutList.size(); j++)
            {
                QPixmap pix = LayoutList.at(j)->grab();
                m_WorkspaceScreenshots[workspaces.at(i)].append(pix);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This slot goes through the widgets in question and takes screenshots of them by using the "grab" function. This works perfectly without the concurrency but it does clog up the main thread and causes the UI to freeze if there are lots of widgets to take screenshots of, which is why I want to move this to a thread.
However once I attempt to run this slot on a thread the grab function causes a crash as the widgets are created and owned by another thread;

```
ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x23ce917b2a0. Receiver 'qt_scrollarea_hcontainer' (of type 'QWidget') was created in thread 0x0x23ce408b650", file kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 577
```

How can I take screenshots of these widgets from the thread I'm currently in without causing a crash?
I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Basic Qt rule: You cannot and should not access the widget's methods from another thread.

Comment: How many widgets are we talking about? How often are you taking screenshots? Can you divide the work in smaller chunks so you can alternate screenshot taking with the regular event loop?

Comment: The amount widgets can go up to 640 widgets, They have to be taken all at once as they represent a "state" of the widget at that moment in time.

Comment: That seems a rather 'brute force' approach to capturing state.  Why not simply save the state of various class members etc. to an `std::ostream` (`std::stringstream` perhaps?) instead?

Comment: @Mr.Grease You may have to rethink your approach then. Instead of grabbing every widget every time, are you in a position to do change tracking on every widget instead?

Comment: Are all the mentioned widgets independent, or they are lay out in a hierarchy? If later is true, you can grab only the parent widget that contains "images" of its children. With this you can decrease the number of widgets to grab.

Comment: @Botje Unfortunately no, I have to grab screenshots of each widget and can't track changes.

Comment: @vahancho These are all laid out in a way that I could take screenshots of the parent widget and be done with it, however the problem is that I'd need to disect the screenshot to get the screenshots of each child widget as they're supposed to be used in different places.

Comment: That approach looks like it could work though. If you can determine a small amount of root widgets you could grab those and use `childWidget.mapTo(rootWidget, childWidget.rect().topLeft())` to figure out where in the pixmap the top left point of the child widget resides. Mutatis mutandis for the bottom right.

Comment: @Mr.Grease, you can grab a single screenshot and easily extract the screenshots of its children using their relative coordinates.